# change a tag content by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to change the text in a tag by JavaScript, by calling JavaScript function from JSP page.

I tried like following but nothing changed !:

JSP Page:

```
            <ul>
                <li><a id="tab1" href = "#tabs-2">Web</a></li>
               <li><a href = "#tabs-3">Images</a></li>
            </ul>
```

JSP code:

```
String textSearch = request.getParameter("txtbox").toLowerCase()+" ";

%>
<script>
     aboutTab(<%=textSearch %>);
</script>
<%
```

JavaScript Code:

```
        function aboutTab(f) {
            document.getElementById("tab1").innerHTML = "HI" + f ;

        }
```

**Edited**

When i did this change it work ! justification?

```js
                   <script>
                                aboutTab(<%="'"+textSearch+"'" %>);
                   </script>
```

Comment: [Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about JSP, but I do know how to answer your question with javascript.This function is pretty broad, but It'll get the job done.

```
function changeVal (TagId,newVal){
    document.getElementById(TagId).value = newVal;
};
function changeText (TagId,newText){
document.getElementById(TagId).textContent = newText;
};
```

Hope This Helps! mark answered if so!